# Objective C: How to call variables from other methods

Tags: objective-c, iphone, variables, uislider

Writing an iPhone App that uses the UISlider class.

The Slider returns some value in its method.

I want to use that value in another method...but since that value is a local variable for the slider method, how would I go about doing this?

The keyword "static" doesnt seem to work because the slider value is not constant...

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance of UISlider class in your main class. And then use that instance to access the current value of Slider.
This may help:[UISlider example](http://www.tuaw.com/2007/09/04/iphone-coding-using-the-slider/)